# Calculating equal area latitudinal bins

Tags: r, geometry, area, sf

I want to generate a simple function for producing equal-area latitudinal bins based on a desired number of bins. I've come up with a bit of a dirty solution which seems computationally expensive and the long-winded way of doing it. So I wanted to ask the community if they had any more straightforward ways of going about this. There doesn't seem to be much out there specifically on latitudinal bins which doesn't require generating some raster/grid of type. Here is my current function:

```
library(sf)
equal_area_lat_bins <- function(n, by = 0.1) {
  # Radius of the Earth
  earth_radius <- 6378137
  # Calculate surface area of the Earth assuming a perfect sphere
  earth_area <- 4 * pi * earth_radius^2
  # What should be the bin area of each bin?
  bin_area <- earth_area / (n)
  # Calculate for 1/4 of longitudinal range to prevent date line issues
  lng <- c(0, 0, 90, 90)
  # Specify number of steps (higher number of steps, increased equality)
  vals <- seq(0, 90, by = by)
  # Set starting index
  indx <- 1
  # Half the number of bins to avoid recalculating hemispheres
  n_half <- n / 2
  # Create empty df for populating
  bins <- data.frame(bin = 1:n_half, min = rep(NA, n_half),
                     max = rep(NA, n_half), area = rep(NA, n_half))
  # Run across desired number of bins
  for (i in 1:n_half) {
    # Set area value to 0
    a <- 0
    # Record starting index
    start_indx <- indx
    while (a < bin_area) {
      # Increase index
      indx <- indx + 1
      # Extract latitudes
      lat <- c(vals[indx-1], vals[indx], vals[indx-1], vals[indx])
      # If NAs are present, index has gone beyond vals length (90 lat)
      if (any(is.na(lat))) {
        indx <- indx - 1
        break
      }
      # Create point dataframe
      p <- data.frame(lng = lng,
                      lat = lat)
      # Create polygon for area calc
      poly <- p %>%
        st_as_sf(coords = c("lng", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% 
        st_bbox() %>% 
        st_as_sfc()
      # Calculate area
      a <- a + as.numeric(st_area(x = poly) * 4)
    }
    # Record final index
    end_indx <- indx
    # Assign breaks
    bins$max[i] <- vals[end_indx]
    bins$min[i] <- vals[start_indx]
    # Assign area value
    bins$area[i] <- a
  }
  # Create southern hemisphere df
  s_bins <- bins
  bins <- bins[order(bins$bin, decreasing = TRUE), ]
  s_bins$min <- s_bins$min * -1
  s_bins$max <- s_bins$max * -1
  # bind data
  bins <- rbind.data.frame(bins, s_bins)
  bins$bin <- 1:nrow(bins)
  row.names(bins) <- NULL
  return(bins)
}
bins <- equal_area_lat_bins(n = 12, by = 0.01)
```

Comment: For a spherical earth model it should be easy to compute the spherical area of a shell between two latitudes, in the same way as the area of the whole shell (4 pi r^2) is done, via calculus. If that formula can be inverted then you can get the latitudes that create a set of shell fragments with equal area.... I'll see if I can find the formulas (or do some calculus myself...).

Comment: Yeah, should be doable via the "area of a spherical cap" formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap since the area of a latitude band is the difference between two spherical caps. Fiddly bit is always working with latitude on the one hand and mathematically define angles on the other... There is also a formula for area given two latitudes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Surface_area_bounded_by_parallel_disks

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks for the quick response! This is indeed what I am looking for! However, I'm not really able to reproduce the example they provide (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Surface_area_bounded_by_parallel_disks). Any idea if their calculation is off or I am messing up the formula?
`(2 * pi) * (6371^2) * abs(sin(90) - sin(66.56))`

Comment: You need to convert all degrees to radians to feed to sin() and cos()... `raddeg = function(deg){deg*pi/180}`.

Comment: @Spacedman That's great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Out of curiosity, could this easily be extended to a WGS 84 ellipsoid?

Comment: For some value of "easily" yes - the equations are going to get a lot more complicated. Beyond me, sorry, and searching "surface area of an ellipsoidal cap" doesn't help much. Partly because they are general solutions and you probably only want oblate ellipsoid...

Comment: I couldn't find anything that didn't dive deep into calculus... I was hoping an approximation could be made using ellipsoid flattening or similar but no luck! Thanks for also taking a look!

Comment: try L3bin https://github.com/hypertidy/L3bin (doesn't do flattening)